# Convertir los datos POST a json en php

Tags: php, json, string

Necesito convertir los datos POST a texto json.
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
$post = POST['datos'];

/*
Aqui va el codigo para convertir $post a '{nombre:Juan,edad:35}'
*/

echo $post;
```

Comment: intenta usando $json = json_encode($post);

Comment: Eso es: intenta algo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisas el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php), la super global `$_POST` es (las negritas son mías):

> **Un array asociativo** de variables pasadas al script actual a través del método POST de HTTP cuando se emplea
> `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` o `multipart/form-data` como
> `Content-Type` de HTTP en la petición.

PHP dispone de la función [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) para crear la representación en JSON de un valor dado. Esta función admite cualquier valor, excepto valores de tipo resource, como indica el Manual de PHP (enlace anterior).

Por tanto, si quieres convertir lo que hay en `$_POST['datos']` (por cierto, no estás poniendo `$_` en tu variable, lo cual es erróneo) en una representación en JSON, puedes hacer esto:

```
$json=json_encode($_POST['datos']);
echo $json;
```

**Salida:**

```
{"nombre":"Juan","edad":35}
```

#### Conversión a variable de PHP

Pero lo anterior no es más que una cadena. Lo interesante de un JSON es poder acceder a sus propiedades, por ejemplo para mostrarlas en pantalla.

Para ello existe [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) el cual:

> Convierte un string codificado en JSON a una variable de PHP.

Para usar `json_decode()` la cadena debe tener una estructura válida y no exceder el límite de recursividad, como dice el Manual de PHP (ver enlace anterior):

> Devuelve el valor codificado en json en un tipo de PHP apropiado. Los
> valores `true`, `false` y `null` son devueltos como `true`, `false` y
> `null` respectivamente. `null` es devuelto si el parámetro json no se
> puede decodificar o si los datos codificados son más profundos que el
> límite de recursividad.

Cuando conviertes tu cadena a variable de PHP, entonces sí la cosa se hace interesante:

```
$json=json_encode($_POST['datos']);
$object=json_decode($json);
var_dump($object);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["nombre"]=>
  string(4) "Juan"
  ["edad"]=>
  int(35)
}
```

Como ves, la variable `$object` que se crea es un objeto de PHP y puedes acceder a sus propiedades, por ejemplo:

```
printf("Nombre: %s, Edad: %d", $object->nombre, $object->edad);
```

**Salida:**

```
Nombre: Juan, Edad: 35
```

Bueno, esto no permite apreciar demasiado la utilidad. Pero, supongamos que en `datos` hay varias personas anidadas, algo así, simulando a `$_POST`:

```
$_POST=array(
             'datos'=>
                array(
                        array('nombre'=>'Juan Pérez', 'edad'=>35),
                        array('nombre'=>'Marta', 'edad'=>25),
                        array('nombre'=>'Pedro', 'edad'=>40),
                )
    );

/*
    Nótese que podemos llamada a json_encode()
    dentro de json_decode()
*/
$allData=json_decode(json_encode($_POST['datos']));
foreach ($allData as $item) {
    printf("Nombre: %-10s \tEdad: %d\n", $item->nombre, $item->edad);
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Nombre: Juan Pérez  Edad: 35
Nombre: Marta       Edad: 25
Nombre: Pedro       Edad: 40
```

Como ves, con tres líneas de código, hemos impreso los datos de todas las personas, al convertir nuestra cadena en un objeto de PHP.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y si, se me olvidó poner $_